# how to launch ios simulator from phonegap

Tags: cordova, ios-simulator

when i try to launch ios simulator from command line by using
`$ phonegap run ios`
i get the below error

> Error: ios-sim was not found. Please download, build and install
> version 1.5 or greater         from
> https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim into your path. Or 'brew install
> ios-sim' using homebrew: [Link](https://brew.sh/)

i even tried copying the above ios-sim folder into my path. still getting an error.

Comment: Are you running on a Mac machine with xCode installed and running? Did you type `brew install ios-sim` into the command line and see ios-sim get installed? After that did you edit the PATH variable in your system and include the path to the ios-sim folder?

Answer (score 32):

**Best Solution:**

1. Make sure you have **XCode** and its command line tools installed and accepted the license agreements
2. Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in terminal:

   > ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
3. Install ios-sim via Homebrew by executing:

   > brew install ios-sim
4. Watch for error messages or upon successfull installation, you should be able to run the iOS Simulator:

   > `phonegap run ios`

---

**Alternative Solution:**

You could try installing ios-sim via npm:

- Head over to http://nodejs.org/ and install node.js (npm will be automatically installed as node's package manager).
- Install ios-sim via npm by executing

> sudo npm install ios-sim -g
>
> if you're on a Windows machine, open the command prompt as administrator and execute `npm install ios-sim` instead

Comment: I was able to get it working another way eventually.  Apparently there was an issue with where node.js was installing the sim to, and also that I needed to globally accept the xcode user agreement through the terminal.

Comment: I had the same issue. First I tried brew, but there was a conflict because of node. So, then I updated ios-sim via npm, then tada! It works.

Comment: ran into the whole update problem too just ran "sudo npm update ios-sim -g"   and wowzers off to a flyer

Comment: I had similar issues, looks like homebrew and npm were stepping on each others' toes. `brew uninstall ios-sim` followed by `npm install ios-sim -g` (may need sudo depending on your setup) did the trick.

Comment: Currently I'm learning Phonegap and many tools seem to have the `Cordova` name so for me I had to run: the following to get the iOS Simulator: `cordova run ios`

Answer (score 5):

**To run on simulator we need to install ios-sim and ios-deploy.**

**Following are steps to run on iOS emulator**

1. Install ios-sim using npm by executing:

   > sudo npm install ios-sim -g
2. Install ios-deploy using npm by executing:

   > sudo npm install ios-deploy -g
3. Make sure your simulator is running
4. Final Command:

   > phonegap run ios --emulator

**If need to run on particular simulator then following are steps:**

1. Find out list of available simulators and their exact name

   > cordova emulate ios --list
2. now run on particular simulator using:

   > cordova emulate ios --target="XXXXXX"

Comment: for mac os 10.12 and above in order to install ios-deploy you need to add the unsafe param
sudo npm install ios-deploy -g --unsafe-perm=true