# phonegap / cordova workflow, which 'www' folder are you intended to develop in?

Tags: cordova, workflow, cordova-3, command-line-interface

When I build a phoneGap app using the commands below

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
```

I get the three following 'www' folders

```
hello/www
hello/platforms/android/www
hello/platforms/ios/www
```

If I modify a file in the folder

```
hello/www
```

And then run the command

```
cordova build ios
```

The changes to

```
hello/www
```

Are written to

```
hello/platforms/ios/www
```

I can then test ios app by running it via xcode. Is this the intended workflow for phoneGap i.e. running the build command every time you want to test the app, or should I be developing directly in

```
hello/platforms/ios/www
```

Comment: yes, that's the workflow. You can do cordova prepare ios, it's faster than build

Answer (score 0):

The procedure you describe is the intended behaviour, if you're making application specific changes then these would be overwritten when you go back to the main folder and build to the specific platform.

It seems long winded but once you get the hang of it its not, using the CLI speeds up the process of installing plugins. If you're looking for platform specific changes then i recommend using if statements within your code.

So the simple answer to your question is edit this folder:

> hello/www

Then build to the relevant platform as desired.

Note that you can build and test your code in one line by using the following command

> cordova emulate ios

This will build your app and push it straight into the simulator providing you have the ios simulator installed.

See [This S.O. Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859966/how-to-launch-ios-simulator-from-phonegap) for instructions on how to do that

Comment: I tried this and it worked. Are there CLI options for running it on different emulators and/or a physical device?

Comment: Yes! `Cordova run ios` will push it straight to your device as long as it's plugged in, and it will work the same with different platforms as long as you have the correct library's installed. So simply change ios to android and it should work the same.